# What's wrong with Loop speed?

Tags: c#, performance, loops, for-loop

I have this simple `for` loop with nothing inside. It takes almost 2 seconds to run, now, but if I replace the `_img.width` with 512 then it runs almost in 0.001 milliseconds. What's the problem? Should I assign a local variable instead of using `_img.width`? I'm wondering why it runs faster since it's just a number.

```
for (int aRowIndex = 0; aRowIndex < _img.width; aRowIndex += subsample)// For por cada fila de cada imagen
{
    for (int aColumnIndex = 0; aColumnIndex < _img.height; aColumnIndex += subsample)//For por cada columna
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: and the value of `_img.Width` itself originally is also 512? maybe it is a property that has to get calculated first and that eats up the time?

Comment: As DrCopyPaste suggests, move the _img.Width and _img.Height out of the loop into local variables to check if the value is taking time to load. This has been the case for me in the past when accessing remote printer settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> why it runs faster since it's just a number

It is not just a number, it is a *property*.  With a nontrivial implementation, unfortunately, there's an underlying unmanaged interop call involved that isn't very cheap.  It blows up to an observable overhead due to the O(n^2) loop complexity.

You can simply solve it by caching the property value yourself:

```
int width = _img.Width;
int height = _img.Height;
for (int aRowIndex = 0; aRowIndex < width; aRowIndex += subsample)
{
    for (int aColumnIndex = 0; aColumnIndex < height; aColumnIndex += subsample)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I did to improve speed. It significantly reduces the time of the whole loop.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the .NET source for `Image.Height` you can see that every type you get the property value it invokes an external call to `gdiplus.dll`. It does not cache the value in .NET memory.

```
/// <summary>Gets the height, in pixels, of this <see cref="T:System.Drawing.Image" />.</summary>
/// <returns>The height, in pixels, of this <see cref="T:System.Drawing.Image" />.</returns>
public int Height
{
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        int result;
        int num = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetImageHeight(new HandleRef(this, this.nativeImage), out result);
        if (num != 0)
        {
            throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(num);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

By the way, this is actually against Microsoft's own guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments it seems that the implementation of Width in Bitmap(which inherits from Image) is not just returning a value.

If you will use ILdsm to look at the implementation you will notice there is a pretty expensive interop.
Here is the code from "Reflector" (which is more readable then IL) :

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public int get_Width()
{
    int num;
    int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetImageWidth(new HandleRef(this, this.nativeImage), out num);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }
    return num;
}
```